# Diffrence between Collection<T> and custom implement class

Tags: vb.net

Some people advice to inherit from Collection to get collection class. Some other people advice to have class and implement interfaces from scratch.  I would like to understand when to use one over another.

I see that when i use:

```
class MyCollection 
       Inherits Collection(Of SomeObject)
```

I have possibility to add, insert, for each etc that's probably because `Collection<T> uses internally List<T>`

However if i just do:

```
class MyCollection : IList(Of SomeObject), IEnumerable<SomeObject>, IEnumerable(Of SomeObject)
          myList As List(Of SomeObject)
```

i can also implement such things like `Add(), Remove(), for each`

Is it like it's good to use Collection(Of T) because it's already contains all of this implemented interfaces and inner List(Of T) rather that implementing all interfaces myself in self class from scratch? Is it the point people advice to inherit from `COllection(Of T)`?

**EDIT (for further discussion):**

```
  Public Class Merge
        Property Size As Integer
        Property Datee As Date
        Property Min As Integer
        Property Max As Integer?
        Property Value As Double

        Public Sub New(min As Integer, max As Integer?, value As Integer)
            Me.Min = min
            Me.Max = max
            Me.Value = value
        End Sub      
    End Class

    Public Enum SortCriteria
        MinThenMax
        MaxThenMin
    End Enum

  Public Class MergeComparer
        Implements IComparer(Of Merge)   'do oddzielnej klasy sortowania obiektu jak tutaj potrzebujemy IComparer a nie IComparable (ten jest bezposrednio na klasie)

        Public SortBy As SortCriteria = SortCriteria.MinThenMax

        Public Function Compare(x As Merge, y As Merge) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Merge).Compare
        'to be implemented
        End Function


    End Class


      Public Class MergeCollection
      Inherits Collection(Of Merge)

    Public SortBy As SortCriteria = SortCriteria.MinThenMax


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Ovveride because
    ''' There could be only one item on list which contains Max prop = Nothing
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="index"></param>
    ''' <param name="item"></param>
    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As Merge)
        if IsNothing(item.Max)
            If Items.Any(Function(myObject) IsNothing(Items.Max)) Then
                Return
            End If
        End If

        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End Sub   

    Public Sub Sort()
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Sort(comparison As Comparison(Of Merge))
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems, comparison)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Sort(comparer As IComparer(Of Merge))
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems, comparer)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If you implement all those interfaces yourself, you'll just be reproducing what `Collection(Of T)` already does for you. If you want a class that implements `IList(Of T)` then there's no point not inheriting `Collection(Of T)` unless you genuinely enjoy wasting your time reinventing the wheel. If you only want to implement `IEnumerable(Of T)` or `ICollection(Of T)` then that's a different story.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i saw inheriting from COllection<T> missing Sort. Should i inherit from Collection<T> and implement I Comparable?

Comment: It's not that it's "missing" a `Sort` method because `Sort` isn't a standard method, i.e. it's not a member of the `IList(Of T)` interface. If you want a `Sort` method then you can add one easily enough. You absolutely should NOT implement `IComparable`. You do that for collection items, not collections. Do you want to be able to compare one collection to another.  Read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html).

Comment: @jmcilhinney I ment  Implements IComparer(Of SomeObject) but then when i implement  Public Function Compare(x As Merge, y As Merge) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Merge).Compare then i still do not see Sort() for my collection. What enables Sort?

Comment: You wouldn't implement `IComparer` either.  That's for objects that you pass to a `Sort` method specifically for the purposes of comparing items of a type.  I explain all that in the blog post I directed you to so I suggest you read it.

Comment: You don't need another example.  I've shown you two ways to sort my example `StringCollection` class by the `Length` property of each `String` item.  Why would sorting your "custom objects" be any different to that?

Comment: Why do you think you need a custom collection in the first place? What is the special logic that this collection handles that the standard ones does not? That might help in the decision in which direction to go.

Comment: The MSDN article for the class does not do a good-enough job at describing exactly how you customize your own derived class to get a collection type of your liking.  You cannot customize Add(), it is not virtual.  But you don't have to, there are 4 customization points.  They are Protected Overridable methods, InsertItem, RemoveItem, SetItem and ClearItems.  So if you want to change the way Add() works, say throwing an exception if you're not happy with the object, then do so in InsertItem.  Adding methods that are not present, like Sort, is not an issue.

Comment: @HansPassant so like adding methods like Sort - Merge class itself or separated class only for comparer should implement IComparable and in clas MergeCollection just create method which would use that right?

Comment: I don't really understand where this is heading, the question started about re-implementing the interfaces.  None of which does anything with sorting.  If you are *only* focused on sorting then consider that you don't have to re-implement a collection class at all.  You might as well use a single Shared method that takes, say, an IList(Of T) argument.

Comment: Read the blog post that I directed you to if you haven't already and [read this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548061) too.  Those two resources and my answer tell you all you need to know about custom collections and sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a custom collection that implements `Collection(Of T)` and then adds it's own `Sort` method:

```
Public Class StringCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of String)

    Public Sub Sort()
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sample usage:

```
Dim strings As New StringCollection

strings.Add("Peter")
strings.Add("Paul")
strings.Add("Mary")

strings.Sort()

For Each s In strings
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

That `Sort` method relies on the `IComparable` implementation of the items themselves.  If you want to support other sorting methods or your items don't implement `IComparable` then you can implement different `Sort` methods, e.g.

```
Public Class StringCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of String)

    Public Sub Sort()
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Sort(comparison As Comparison(Of String))
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems, comparison)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sample usage:

```
Dim strings As New StringCollection

strings.Add("Peter")
strings.Add("Paul")
strings.Add("Mary")

strings.Sort(Function(a, b) a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length))

For Each s In strings
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

In that case, we're explicitly comparing the `String` items by their `Length` rather than their implicit "alphabetic" `IComparable` implementation.

You can include an overload of `Sort` for every relevant overload of `Array.Sort` and/or you can provide your own explicit comparisons if you want.  Note that one of those overloads takes an `IComparer`.  Here's how you might make use of that:

```
Public Class StringCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of String)

    Public Sub Sort()
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Sort(comparison As Comparison(Of String))
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems, comparison)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub Sort(comparer As IComparer(Of String))
        Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

        Array.Sort(allItems, comparer)

        For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
            Items(i) = allItems(i)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's an example comparer:

```
Public Class StringLengthComparer
    Implements IComparer, IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Return Compare(CStr(x), CStr(y))
    End Function

    Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
    End Function

End Class
```

Sample usage:

```
Dim strings As New StringCollection

strings.Add("Peter")
strings.Add("Paul")
strings.Add("Mary")

Dim comparer As New StringLengthComparer

strings.Sort(comparer)

For Each s In strings
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

We're sorting the items by their `Length` again but, this time, we're using an object that implements `IComparer` to make the comparisons rather than a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate.  You should notice, though, that the `Compare` method of the `IComparer` in this last example takes pretty much the exact same form as the Lambda used to create the `Comparison(Of T)` delegate in the previous example.

Comment: First you made the mistake of not doing what I did in my code.  You then compounded that by not bother to reread my code to check whether you did it properly and asked me tp waste more of my time telling you to read what I've already posted. This is not the way to make friends.

Comment: I see so i need to implement Comparer in separate class or in class Merge itself - means not in collection class itself. And in collection class itself just to create method/-s to call the comparers am i right? Look now please at Edit section now should be fine. Can you confirm?